# Programmatically send Outlook task updates

Tags: vb.net, outlook, outlook-addin

Does anyone know how to programmatically send an outlook task update in either C# or VB? I can't seem to find any information online about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [VSTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office)'s Outlook Interop libraries to interact with [Task Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184608.aspx). I have used this library to work with MailItems and am aware of the possibility to interact with other Outlook items like Tasks, Calendar items and journal items.