# Outlook folder for sent tasks

Tags: outlook, vsto, ms-office, add-in, outlook-addin

Does anyone know what `Folder` Outlook stores its **Sent Tasks** in? I'm trying to design an addin that includes providing an new interface for tasks the user has sent out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sent Tasks** are stored in the **Sent Items** folder [`OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.oldefaultfolders.aspx).

```cs
Outlook.Folder sentMail = this.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail) as Outlook.Folder;
```

Comment: To find which ones in the sent folder are tasks would I just check to see if their message class = IPM.task?

Comment: [`IPM.TaskRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861573.aspx) and possibly `IPM.TaskRequest.Update` depending upon what you are interested in. `IPM.Task` message class is primarily used within the **Tasks** `Folder`

Comment: You may have just helped me with another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732142/programmatically-send-outlook-task-updates/12732179#12732179) I had as well. I am also looking to programmatically send task updates so that the changes will also appear in the task owners list of sent tasks. I had known there was an IPM.TaskRequest.Update class.